# Adding trailing layout attributes to UIbutton in custom cell of Table View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I have created a custom cell with three UILabels and one imageView and a button.When i run my code on iOS simulator it looks fine with device as iphone 4 and 5 but as i switch to iphone 6 the imageView and button shifts to left because of change in width of screen size.

So to resolve this issue i tried to add constraints on the imageView and on button ,but when i run this app with constraints the button and imageView are not showing up on simulator screen.

so can anybody please tell me how can i add constraints to my cell.

This is how it looks in iphone 6.

[image]

and this is from iphone 4 and 5

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Screen size is different. U must use constraint.

Comment: i know that and i tried that also but as i add constraints on my imageview and Button it disappears from the screen,and thats where i am stuck..

Comment: add image only right,top and width,height. for button bottom,right and width,height. delete all other constraits.